# Can I use OpCodes.Ldsfld without using FieldInfo?

Tags: c#, cil, ilgenerator

I want to avoid using GetType and GetField. Can I just use a string with Ldsfld? I have included a mock-up of what I'm trying to accomplish below. As you can see I'm new to IL Generation - I'm trying to remove some of the cost the cost of reflection in my application.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static string TextBox1 = "Hello World!";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dm = new DynamicMethod("My_method",
                typeof(string), null, true);

            var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, "string ConsoleApplication10.Program::TextBox1");
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            var func = (Func<string>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>));
            var s = func();

            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must use reflection to generate the IL correctly.  The point is that you only do it once, the DynamicMethod can be used any number of times and does *not* use reflection.

Comment: Thanks. In my application I have a child process that is started many many times and on each process start I incur the reflection cost. I will investigate other ways to remove/optimize my use of reflection.

Comment: That makes excessively little sense, starting a process is orders of magnitude more expensive than reflection.  Don't guess at a perf problem, you'll guess wrong.

Comment: Also note, that ILGenerator is almost never necessary. It is far easier to generate code using expression trees. Probably, you used a legacy tutorial (>5 years ago).

Comment: Yup - the the cost of the reflection in my application is significantly less than the cost of starting the processes. I have been measuring using the stopwatch class and have determined that in the grand scheme of things my use of reflection is worth spending time on as there is only so far I can take process pooling and reducing process start-up time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, [the documentation for `OpCodes.Ldsfld`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldsfld) says:

> The following `Emit` method overload can use the `ldsfld` opcode:
>
> - `ILGenerator.Emit(OpCode, FieldInfo)`

And to get `FieldInfo` if you know the name of the field, you need to use reflection.